# No obtengo el resultado esperado en Oracle

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Tengo dos consultas en `sql`, el primer query me devuelve 422 numeros de cuenta (su campo es *G300CTA*, lo siento por el nombre de la tabla, cuando llegue ya estaban asi) el cual necesito implementar dichos números de cuenta en un  segundo query para obtener otros valores:

**Primer query:**

```
select M000.G300CTA
        from MRCJ000 M000, GSCF300 G300,  USEJE000 U000, CNLF000  C000
        WHERE G300.G300CTA = M000.G300CTA
        and U000.UIDEJE000 = M000.UIDEJE000 
        and C000.CUUID000  = M000.CUUID000 and
        C000.CUUID000 = '2' and U000.UIDEJE000 = '41'
```

**Resultado del primer query:**

[image: 422 numeros de cuenta]

Bien, ahora necesito saber como es posible implementar dichos números de cuenta en el siguiente query, el cual solo necesito que consulte los 422 números de cuenta.

Intente implementando la función `IN` como `EXISTS` pero no obtengo el resultado esperado.

El siguiente query me devuelve no solo 422 números de cuenta, sino que me devuelve practicamente todas las cuentas que tengo en la base de datos, es como si omitiera el `IN`.

**Segundo query**

```
select 
                     G300.G300CTA   as CUENTA
                   , G300.G300UUID  as CODIGO
                   , G300.G300NCTL  as NOMBRE
                   , G006.G006TDOD  as TIPO_DOCUMENTO
                   , C002.C002NDOC  as NUM_DOCUMENTO
                   , G300.G300AGE   as COD_AGENCIA
                   , G009.G009AGED  as AGENCIA
                   , G008.G008PRON  as PRODUCTO
                   , G305.G305S02   as DISPONIBLE
                   , G305.G305S01   as SALDO_FINAL
                   , G305.G305FDIA  as FECHA
                   , row_number() over (partition by G300.G300CTA  order by G305.G305FDIA desc) NumFila
              from GSCF305 G305
                   inner join GSCF300 G300 on G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID
                   inner join CCLF002 C002 on G300.G300CLI = C002.C001CLI
                   inner join GTGF006 G006 on G006.G005TDOC = C002.C002TDOC
                   inner join VCVF002 V002 on G300.G300UUID = V002.V001UUID
                   inner join GTGF009 G009 on G300.G300AGE = G009.G009AGE
                   inner join GTGF008 G008 on G300.G300PROD  = G008.G007PROD
             where G300.G300TCTA = 'V'
             AND G300.G300CTA IN (select M000.G300CTA
                            from MRCJ000 M000, GSCF300 G300,  USEJE000 U000, CNLF000  C000
                        WHERE G300.G300CTA = M000.G300CTA
                        and U000.UIDEJE000 = M000.UIDEJE000 
                        and C000.CUUID000  = M000.CUUID000 and
                        C000.CUUID000 = '2' and U000.UIDEJE000 = '41')
             and trunc(G305.G305FDIA) <= to_Date('2019/02/15', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
             order by G305.G305FDIA desc
```

Me disculpo de antemano si no me doy a explicar

Comment: Un recomendación que nada tiene que ver con el problema, por las dudas siempre cuando uses el IN con una subconsulta, agrega a esta ultima un DISTINCT o un GROUP BY. Con respecto al prtoblema, entonces es el query principal el que no te retorna las cuentas que estás esperando, quita la clausula IN y revisa las cuentas que te estaría retornando

Comment: vos esperas que el query total devuelva 422 registros? porque tal vez, hay relaciones NxM y entonces los registros son mas...